# How to get the only value from the Queried data

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get the screensavertimeoutvalue from the GPO.

```
Import-module -Name PolicyFileEditor
$UserDir = "$env:windir\system32\GroupPolicy\User\registry.pol"
$RegPath = 'Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Control Panel\Desktop'
$RegName = 'ScreenSaveTimeOut'
Get-PolicyFileEntry -Path $UserDir -Key $RegPath -ValueName $RegName | select Data
```

I got the value as

### Data

60

How to get only 60 instead of the complete value?

Comment: `(Get-PolicyFileEntry -Path $UserDir -Key $RegPath -ValueName $RegName | select Data).Data` should work, without testing it myself.

Comment: @Drew Please don't answer in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Add `-ExpandProperty` https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/select-expandproperty-propertyname/

```
Get-PolicyFileEntry -Path $UserDir -Key $RegPath -ValueName $RegName | Select -ExpandProperty Data
```